# Views Carousel module in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I have uploaded the [view carousel](http://drupal.org/project/viewscarousel) module in my project. I have created a Content Type (named image). I have added one field  (imagefield) to this Content Type. After this I created the view, but there is only one image showing in the slider.

If some one has any information regarding this, please help me.
(all images are showing in preview, not just one)

Comment: you should really clarify your question. is the android tag accurate?

Comment: by mistake this tag is added. the right tag is drupal

Comment: I edited your question for clarity - if you disagree with any of the edits I made, please correct as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the module, but here's my two cents:

The [Views Carousel](http://drupal.org/project/viewscarousel) module is deprecated in favor of the [jCarousel](http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module. Use the newer module instead. jCarousel will have better support (it already has a Drupal 7 release) whereas Views Carousel is a dead-end.

Comment: Thanks Buddy this is really helpful.and easy to use